# Acquire photo in wpf mvvm

Tags: wpf

I am creating a id card making project in wpf mvvm.I want to implement a feature to acquire photo from camera. how can implement this?Please give me some sample code.

Comment: You'll find that you struggle to get good answers while you're failing to accept an answer to your existing questions.  Go and nurture the other questions a bit.

Answer (score 1):

Will is right, but in the meantime there is no native camera support in WPF, but you can have a look at the sample project at http://blog.catenalogic.com/post/WPF-Webcam-Control-part-2.aspx as a starting point.